# Python: make turtle move based on user input

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

What's wrong with this code that is supposed to make a turtle move to a certain direction based on user input?

```
import turtle


myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()



instruction = input()




xCor = myTurtle.position() + 10
yCor = myTurtle.position() - 0


if instruction == "right":
    myTurtle.goto(xCor,yCor)
```

PS: I'm a beginner so please don't make me frustrated by giving an answer that's really complicated xD

Comment: Please post the *actual code* as text in your post, not an image of your code.

Comment: Post your code as text

Comment: Im sorry, but it was too much trouble to do that, since it wouldn't let me have indentation in the text, so I just posted it as a image instead(It's the first time that I actually post a question on stack overflow so that's why I was so confused)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line (and the related `yCor` one):

```
xCor = myTurtle.position() + 10
```

`position()` returns a tuple with both X & Y, not a number.  What you probably want is this:

```
import turtle

myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()

instruction = input()

xCor = myTurtle.xcor() + 10
yCor = myTurtle.ycor() - 0

if instruction == 'right':
    myTurtle.goto(xCor, yCor)

turtle.done()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @cdlane At first I was a bit confused because I saw that the variable xcor/ycor was equal to myTurtle.xCor/yCor, but now I changed the variable names to xPos/yPos instead.